# How to make a report with count of type of cases in each month in Acess 2010

Tags: ms-access, report, reporting, ms-access-2010

I have a database is access with each record having a date and yes/no type columns for each record which shows which category the record comes under. I want to create a report which shows the types of cases in each month by taking a date range as a parameter through prompts. I have done the prompt part but I'm not sure how the query should be to show values for each month in that date range. Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing the details of your tables, you can Group by the Year and month either as separated columns or with a combined expression like this:

```
Year(Orders.OrderDate) & '-' & Right('0' & Month(Orders.OrderDate), 2)
```

If you need more specific help, provide an example of what you have and what you want to accomplish.

**Edit:**

With the additional info, if i understand correctly you have something like this:

```
Case    Date      Threat    Stalking    Bullying    ...
1234    24/12/12  Yes       No          No
...
```

And you want something like this:

```
Date      Threats   Stalking    Bullying
12/12     3         2           10
```

Then, you can do more/less it like this:

```
Select Year(Cases.Date) & '/' & Right('0' & Month(Cases.Date), 2) As Date, ThreatQuery.Cases As Threats, StalkingQuery.Cases, ...
From Cases, (Select Count(*) From Cases Where Cases.Threats == 'Yes' And Cases.Date Between @Param And @Param2) ThreatQuery, (Select Count(*)...) StalkingQuery, ...
Where Cases.Date Between @Param And @Param2
```

Note that this query uses multiple subqueries (one for each type of case), so you may want to be sure that the subqueries are right first, for this, you can just check one, given that all are the same, only change depending of the case's type.

Comment: Hi @Miguel Garcia,

I have a table which has information for each violence case in campus. In this, I have columns which marks if that case falls under that category, like threat, stalking, etc. Each case has a date as well. What i am trying to do is trying to do is to try and find out is to make the user enter a date range and with that input, show the total number of cases for the months that come under that range. Example 3 cases of threat, 2 of stalking, 1 of bullying in Jan, 4 of threat, 5 of stalking, 3 of bulling in feb and so on. I'm kind of lost. Please help me out with this