# Dataset with dynamic columns in tablix/matrix

Tags: reporting-services, dataset, ssrs-2008, reporting, reportingservices-2005

I have a dataset that can come with 5 columns, columns 6, 7, 10, 20, or even 100.
At least two are static, the remaining are dynamic (am making a scale according to a table exists in the database).

How can I implement this in Reporting Services?

How do I specify the field of tablix that the value is dynamic?

The end result would be this:

```
|   TITLE | ENUNCIATION | GOOD | VERY GOOD | BAD | VERY BAD |
-------------------------------------------------------------
| title 1 |  question 1 |    5 |         3 |   1 |        0 |
| title 2 |  question 2 |    1 |         0 |   3 |        0 |
| title 3 |  question 3 |    0 |         0 |   1 |        0 |

|   TITLE | ENUNCIATION |   1  |     2     |  3  |     4    |
-------------------------------------------------------------
| title 1 |  question 1 |    5 |         3 |   1 |        0 |
| title 2 |  question 2 |    1 |         0 |   3 |        0 |
| title 3 |  question 3 |    0 |         0 |   1 |        0 |
```

**Note**: The first two are static, the remaining dynamics.

**EDIT:**

I have this table:

```
|   ID_SCALE  | ID_SCALE_ENTRY   | NAME          |
--------------------------------------------------
|      1       |        1        |    GOOD       |    
|      1       |        2        |    VERY GOOD  |   
|      1       |        3        |    BAD        |   
|      1       |        4        |    VERY BAD   |    
|      2       |        1        |       1       |    
|      2       |        2        |       2       |
|      2       |        3        |       3       |
|      2       |        4        |       4       |
|      2       |        5        |       5       |
|      2       |        6        |       6       |
|      2       |        7        |       7       |
```

**EDIT + NOTE:** 
I want to show exactly as shown in the first table. The problem is that (Good, Very Good, Bad, Very Bad, 1, 2, 3, 4) fields are created dynamically and it is not possible to specify this in the tablix.

An example: When I want the field value of the dataset, i put this expression Fields!Good.value But now imagine that it is not "Good" but "1" Fields! Good.value no longer exists. Conclusion, is a dataset with dynamic columns.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**First** - You should use Matrix for that.

**Second** - To accomplish what you want, in the method you return the data you must return at least three data fields.

Ex:

```
ColDescription - Column description
StaticRowDescription - Row description / static column value
Value - The real value for that column/row combination.
```

Got it?

Your Matrix should then be like this:

```
| Any Text               | [ColDescription] |
| [StaticRowDescription] | [Value]          |
```

**EDIT**:

Forgot to mention that Any text is my static column in this example. You can add more to match your need.

**---------------------------------------------------------------**

An example due to your comment.

This is how you would implement in your return method:

Let's say you have one static column `Description` and the others (n).

```
public IEnumerable<YourReturnClass> GetData(int param) 
{
    List<YourReturnClass> returnList = new List<YourReturnClass>();
    foreach (var row in allYourRows())
    {
        foreach (var col in row.getColumns())
        {
            returnList.add(new YourReturnClass(){
                StaticRowDescription = row.Description,
                ColDescription = col.Description,
                Value = myValueAccordingToCurrentColumnXRow()
            });
        }
    }

    return returnList;
}
```

and this as your matrix:

```
| Description            | [ColDescription] |
| [StaticRowDescription] | [Value]          |
```

That way if you had one row in `allYourRows()` with a description "Expenses" and two columns with the names "Gas" and "Electricity" you would have this as your matrix result:

```
| Description | Gas | Electricity |
-----------------------------------
| Expenses    | 25  | 150         |
```

Better?

***This is just to explain how matrix works, the way you get your data might be different than the one portraited.***

The report (RDL) will be the same, the only change is in how you get your data. If you have a table like this:
*(this would be a table from your database (where you have stored your data))*

```
| RowDescription | DynamicColumnHeader | Value |
------------------------------------------------
| Year 2013      | January             | 500   |
| Year 2013      | February            | 850   |
| Year 2013      | March               | 265   |
| Year 2014      | February            | 965   |
```

Then your report would look like this:

```
| Description | January | February | March|
-------------------------------------------
| Year 2013   | 500     | 850      | 265  |
| Year 2014   |         | 965      |      |
```

Got the idea?

I attached an image of how your report would look like:

[image]

NEW EDIT:

```
|   TITLE | ENUNCIATION    | [NAME]                          |
-------------------------------------------------------------
| [title] |  [enunciation] |  [ID_SCALE] OR [ID_SCALE_ENTRY] |
```

*or a multiplication, sum, etc...

EDIT BASED ON LAST COMMENT:

```
|   TITLE | ENUNCIATION    | [NAME]                          |
-------------------------------------------------------------
| [title] |  [enunciation] | [Count(NAME)]                   |
```

Is that it?

Comment: I dont understand the second part. The dataset returns what you can see in the table.

Comment: @sh0rt6r Yes, that's right. Can you explain what you didn't understand, or let me know if it was the whole thing so I can try to ellaborate?

Comment: I do not understand because I'm going to create a method and with that intent. If you can specify more.

Comment: @sh0rt6r the code is just to explain how you can use matrix. How do you call the report? Do you use some web service, just call the report from SSRS, Stored Procedure? Be more specific so I can give a more specific answer.

Comment: I only call the report in SSRS (for now) why can not I make code and thus limits me a bit.

Comment: @sh0rt6r check my new update. You must have your data somewhere... how you draw the report (RDL) will not change. The only change is in how you get your data. Since I don't know how you do that I gave a broad example. Hope it helps.

Comment: @sh0rt6r ok, and what is the relationship between them? I already saw that "NAME" is your dynamic column header, what about the others?

Comment: the first table is only the result of a procedure performed by me.

Comment: @sh0rt6r Ok, I get it, but how do you want to show them at the report?

Comment: i edited one more time the question... see edit + notes please.

Comment: @sh0rt6r I still don't get the relationship... but I can see, as I said, that your column header will be "NAME". in your example you have Good associated to 5, 1 and 0, and in your table you have good associated to 1 and 1. Anyway, I updated my question with what I could understand, I'm using your exact example, I just don't know what you want as value.

Comment: @sh0rt6r Ok, check my new update. If that's now the field you want to count just change NAME for the appropriate field (be it ID_SCALE, ID_SCALE_ENTRY, etc)

Comment: @sh0rt6r When you add a matrix it will automatically create a static column and a grouped column, that's the dynamic one. Just add a matrix and you'll see it. For your case you'll have to a add second static column, so you'll match your need. Just right click the static column and select add new column to the left or right.

Comment: i know that... but the field name changes... and i cant do "Fields!good.value" when "good" not exists... you imagine that is a number i have to put "Fields!2.value

Comment: @sh0rt6r I think you didn't understand how this works. You are not going to use Fields!ContentOfColumn.Value ... you should use Fields!ColumnHeader.Value. If you take a look at my example adapted to your situation and just change it to the names of your table, it should work.

Comment: Yes... but the dataset can come with 5 fields, as can come with 7 fields, and may have different field names...

Comment: @sh0rt6r Again, either you are trying to do something too different, or you didn't get how matrix works. Dataset fields are static, the amount of lines is what changes. If you are looking to represent your table using a dataset you would have only three fields in your dataset (the number of table columns), as I explained to you. Your "columns" would be items of your list.

Comment: The image of the report is grouped by some field? Have RowGroup or ColumnGroup?

Comment: @sh0rt6r both (Column group and row group). this is how matrix works. that's how it's able to work with dynamic content.

Comment: Now i understand... but in my report is giving me some strange values ​​.... you group by what field?

Comment: @sh0rt6r you must group by the field (column in your table) that has the columns' names for your matrix.

Comment: @eestein, please do not vandalize your answers. That is not appropriate on this site.

Comment: There are definitely frustrating users on SO, but that's life. Do your best, ignore them and move on.

Comment: You got enough upvotes from me to balance out most of the downvotes.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is know as a [Pivot grid](http://www.dbxtra.com/help-file/Pivot_Grid.htm), this is made to summarize data, it contains a row area (where Title and Enunciation fields go), a column area (Where the Q_Name field goes) and an area for the data you want to summarize (in your case a count of something i belive).

[image: Pivot grid in DBxtra]

You can, of course, do this on pure SQL, but it's a nightmare to do and maintain, even if you have a fixed number of columns. if you are more interested on this approach you can take a look at my answer here: [How to make a report with count of type of cases in each month in Acess 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13918536/how-to-make-a-report-with-count-of-type-of-cases-in-each-month-in-acess-2010/13924197#13924197).

Disclaimer: The tool featured in the screenshot is [DBxtra](http://www.dbxtra.com/), a tool i promote for reporting and business intelligence.

Comment: The problem is what should be done in SSRS-2008 dataset can come with 5 fields, as can come with 7 fields, and may have different field names.

Comment: Actually DBxtra can handle this with out changing anything, it doesn't matter how many columns your pivotgrid may have, as long as the fields are ordered the way i showed you in the screenshot (it's dynamic). If you go the pure SQL route, you may want to create an store procedure to handle the variable number of columns.